# Why won't my app display the layout I made when I move to the specific activity in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am building an app that returns a list of Github Users from the api on the `Main Activity`, and the detail of the selected user on the `Detail User Activity`. When I run the app, the `Main Activity` shows the list just fine using `RecyclerView`, but when I pressed on one of the users, my app moves to that activity but won't show anything. Also in my Logcat, there's an error that says No adapters attached, skipping layout. Even though I don't have any `RecyclerView` inside my detail activity.

Here's my `MainActivity` :

```
package com.example.githubuser

import android.app.SearchManager
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.githubuser.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        mainViewModel.listUsers.observe(this) { listUsers ->
            val adapter = UsersAdapter(listUsers)
            binding.rvUsers.adapter = adapter
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            binding.rvUsers.layoutManager = layoutManager
        }


        mainViewModel.isLoading.observe(this) {
            showLoading(it)
        }

    }

    private fun showUsers(listUsers: List<ItemsItem>) {
        val adapter = UsersAdapter(listUsers)
        binding.rvUsers.adapter = adapter
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvUsers.layoutManager = layoutManager
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu)

        val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as SearchView

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
        searchView.queryHint = resources.getString(R.string.search_hint)

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(que: String): Boolean {
                showLoading(true)
                getUserSearchData(query = que)
                searchView.clearFocus()
                return true
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
        return true
    }

    private fun getUserSearchData (query : String){
        ApiConfig.getApiService().getUsers(query = query).enqueue(object : Callback<GithubResponse>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<GithubResponse>,
                response: Response<GithubResponse>
            ) {
                showLoading(false)
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val filteredUsers = response.body()?.items?.filter { it.login.contains(query, true) }
                    showUsers(filteredUsers ?: emptyList())
                }else{
                    Log.e("MainViewModel", "onFailure: ${response.message()}")
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<GithubResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                showLoading(false)
                Log.d("TAG", "${t.message}")
            }
        })
    }

    private fun showLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
        binding.progressBar.visibility = if (isLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

Here's my `UsersAdapter`:

```
package com.example.githubuser

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class UsersAdapter(private var listUsers: List<ItemsItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_USER = "user"
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_users, viewGroup, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = listUsers[position]
        myViewHolder.tvUser.text = user.login
        Glide.with(myViewHolder.ivUser)
            .load(listUsers[position].avatarUrl)
            .into(myViewHolder.ivUser)

        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(myViewHolder.itemView.context, DetailUserActivity::class.java)
            val userResponse = UserResponse(
                gistsUrl = "",
                reposUrl = "",
                followingUrl = "",
                createdAt = "",
                login = user.login,
                type = "",
                blog = "",
                subscriptionsUrl = "",
                updatedAt = "",
                siteAdmin = false,
                company = "",
                id = user.id,
                publicRepos = 0,
                gravatarId = "",
                organizationsUrl = "",
                starredUrl = "",
                followersUrl = "",
                publicGists = 0,
                url = "",
                receivedEventsUrl = "",
                followers = 0,
                avatarUrl = user.avatarUrl,
                eventsUrl = "",
                htmlUrl = "",
                following = 0,
                name = "",
                location = "",
                nodeId = ""
            )
            intent.putExtra(UsersAdapter.EXTRA_USER, userResponse)
            intent.putExtra("photo", user.avatarUrl)
            myViewHolder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

    override fun getItemCount() = listUsers.size

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvUser: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_users)
        val ivUser: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_users)
    }
}
```

And here's my `DetailUserActivity`:

```
package com.example.githubuser

import DetailViewModel
import android.media.Image
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.githubuser.UsersAdapter.Companion.EXTRA_USER
import com.example.githubuser.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class DetailUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    private lateinit var adapter: UsersAdapter

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_NAME = "extra_name"
        const val EXTRA_USERNAME = "extra_username"
        const val EXTRA_FOLLOWERS = "extra_followers"
        const val EXTRA_FOLLOWING = "extra_following"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[DetailViewModel::class.java]
//        adapter = UsersAdapter(ItemsItem)

        val tv_name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
        val avatar_user = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.userPhoto)
        val tv_username = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.username)
        val tv_followers = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.followers)
        val tv_following = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.following)

        val user = intent.getParcelableExtra<UserResponse>("user_key")

        val login = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME)
        if (login != null) {
            viewModel.getDetailUser(login)
        }

        viewModel.userDetail.observe(this, Observer {
            if (user != null){
                showLoading(false)
                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(user.avatarUrl)
                    .into(avatar_user)
                tv_name.text = user.name
                tv_username.text = user.login
//                tv_company.text = user.company
//                tv_location.text = user.location
                tv_followers.text = user.followers.toString()
                tv_following.text = user.following.toString()
            }
        })
    }
    private fun showLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
        binding.progressBar.visibility = if (isLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

[image: This is my Main Activity]
[image: And this is my Detail User Activity when I pressed one of the users from the Main Activity]

I tried looking for this specific error on other questions but I can't seem to find an answer.

This is my stack trace error (note that I also have an additional warning about my Glide module at the end):
[image]
[image]

Comment: You  are sending/putting the userResponse model with key -> UsersAdapter.EXTRA_USER
But trying to get it with a different key -> "user_key"
Use same key (String value) for both

Comment: That doesn't seem to change it. I tried your solution just now and my DetailUserActivity still shows nothing.

Comment: Also you are using an obervable from ViewModel but you are still updating UI from the userResponse received in intent.
Try updating the views just after getting the user model from intent.

Comment: The answer added by @ninhnau19 addresses your view not showing issue

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second comment? I'm not sure I understand because I'm fairly new to learning Kotlin and Android development. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe problem is your layout

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

this line have in your Detail activity. it should be ActivityDetailBinding, or something else. You could try

And please post your stack trace error

Edit :

In your adapter, you put 2 extras to your intent:

```
intent.putExtra(UsersAdapter.EXTRA_USER, userResponse)
intent.putExtra("photo", user.avatarUrl)
myViewHolder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
```

BUT, in detail activity, you get value with wrong key:

```
val user = intent.getParcelableExtra<UserResponse>("user_key")
val login = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME)
```

Since you are getting the user model from intent extras, You can update your UI with that data -

```
val user = intent.getParcelableExtra<UserResponse?>(UsersAdapter.EXTRA_USER)

if (user != null){
                showLoading(false)
                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(user.avatarUrl)
                    .into(avatar_user)
                tv_name.text = user.name
                tv_username.text = user.login
                tv_followers.text = user.followers.toString()
                tv_following.text = user.following.toString()
            }
```

Comment: This fixed my view not showing error. However, the contents of the views are still showing the default values from the XML, not how I wanted which is displaying data from the API. Btw, I've updated my question to show the stack trace error.